# Mail function fails

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, debugging, send-mail

For some reason `mail()` function fails when we try to send emails, I debugged the Magento base code and I found that it generates a call to mail function like this:

```
$result = mail('test@test.net', 'My Test Message', "I'm sending a test message",  $header, '-f');
```

I tested this in a simple PHP page and in fact it doesn't work, that's weird because I debugged the same Magento code in our old server and the call is the same and there the mail function works as expected.

In order to make it work I tried to remove the last parameter and then the email is sent

```
$result = mail('test@test.net', 'My Test Message', "I'm sending a test message",  $header);
```

and also I tested the next and the email is sent too

```
$result = mail('test@test.net', 'My Test Message', "I'm sending a test message",  $header, '-f webmaster@example.com');
```

So I don't know why the magento call is not working, I think it's related to the server configuration or PHP configuration because the same call works as expected in our old server, but I'm not sure.

Our old server was Windows Server and now we're over Ubuntu server and my PHP v5.5.9.

[image: I was searching for information and I found that the flag this in the release notes for 1.9 version]

**UPDATE**
I received information from one of the technical guy and now I know that the server is using postfix to send emails. 
This is a log that I received:

```
Jun 17 15:39:58 web01 postfix/sendmail[21502]: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
Jun 17 15:41:07 web01 postfix/sendmail[21697]: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
```

Comment: Maybe it works, but gets into spam folder?

Comment: @Amasty No they are not in the spam, the mail function fails, it returns false so any email is sent

Comment: What does the server's mail log say?

Comment: @NickWeisser I added that information to the question, the server is using postfix to send emails instead of sendmail

Comment: If the time stamp matches with your test then the message seems to be sent correctly, but the from header is not a real email address so it's probably being classified as spam by the receiving server. So it's not a Magento problem, but a mail server configuration problem.

Comment: @NickWeisser no they are not send, I mean I put on this post fake addresses, but if I test without "-f" flag it sends the mails, and putting the "-f" flag any email will be sent

Comment: Your second last line in the mail log states that it was sent. You need to either sent the log from the failed sending attempt or tail the log file while testing, otherwise it's not efficient, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)

Comment: @NickWeisser I confirmed and when I try to send emails the error log registers this:
`Jun 17 15:39:58 web01 postfix/sendmail[21502]: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
Jun 17 15:41:07 web01 postfix/sendmail[21697]: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]`

Comment: There you have it, you might want post that on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not in Magento itself, but is in between PHP and your OS. I'm going to try to answer it anyway.

The PHP `mail()` function accepts the following arguments (from [PHP.net/mail](http://php.net/mail)):

> `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

So the difference is in the last parameter, as I understand. This last parameter is passed down your mail sending program as additional command line parameter directly. This explains why this PHP code could work on one machine, but not on the other.

Check the logs of your mail program, probably [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html) on Ubuntu. Sendmail accepts the *from* parameter in the form of `-f name`. So setting it as `-f` without a name would probably not work.

You could also try one of the other StackExchange websites that are more ontopic on this part.